# Two repeated uses of 'under' in one sentence? Would it bother you?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, redundancy, terminology

Is the following sentence perfectly normal/OK?

A system was developed to integrate the internet and cell phones **under** the SuperSpeed framework by generalizing XCP-IP **under** the X-Transmission framework.

Does the usage of under sound repetitive here?  Would it bother you at all -- 
if 'under' is appropriate in each case? If it still does, how much (ASSUMING there is another way to rewrite the first part of the sentence to get rid of the first under -- then how much would you be bothered by this suboptimal sentence structure? )?

Comment: Please don't post the same question here and on **[ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/421888/two-identical-prepositions-in-a-sentence)**.

Comment: Not familiar with the tech being discussed, but would "*using* xxx protocol/framework" work for either portion? There is clearly a difference, and the English definitions aren't the problem: "developing xxx application *using* the ZZZ framework" vs "integrating two different technologies *under* the (new) YYY protocol" are talking about different kinds of things.

Comment: using is not very appropriate for either one of them.

Comment: Ok, then stick with what you've got. In technical writing, technical precision trumps broad English guidelines about repeating words. (See, I used technical twice! And both were necessary!)

Comment: but say there is another way to rewrite the first part of the sentence to get rid of the first under -- then how much would you be bothered by this suboptimal sentence structure? '

Answer (score 3):

When writing about technical topics, repetitive language is a virtue, not a fault. Is each use of the word *under* individually the best word for the intended meaning at that point in the sentence?
If so, then use *under* as many times as you need to.
If not, use word(s) that convey the intended meaning more clearly.

Comment: yes, each use is appropriate for the respective context in each part of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

A [better](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=within+that+framework%2Cunder+that+framework&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwithin%20that%20framework%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cunder%20that%20framework%3B%2Cc0) alternative to **under the ... framework** is ***within* the ... framework**.